# Monitoring contract event filters with geth --light

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3.py

I'm trying to sync 2 ethereum nodes with Main network. It's talking days.

I've an application that filters "Transfer" events on a specific contract.
Something like

```
abi = ''
address = ''
toggle = False

def get_entries():
  global toggle

  contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, address=address)

  tfilter = contract.on('Transfer', {'fromBlock': 0, 'toBlock': 'latest'})

  return tfilter.get(only_changes = toggle)

  toggle = True
```

Since it's days to sync in normal mode ( I also tried --fast --cache=2048), if I could run an another node with --light flag, will above even work? does the --light mode support filtering contract events?

In my case I don't need any event from past, I just need to capture contract events from this point forward.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Ethereum in **--syncmode light** and it doesn't have support for filters.

Check this for reference: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3752